# synchronous jquery json request

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, synchronous

I need to make a synchronous request to the last.fm API, but when I use GET and json together, the request becomes asynchronous.

my code:

```
$.ajax({
      async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getimages&artist="+artist+"&api_key="+apiKey+"&format=json&callback=?",
    success: function(html){
          imgURL = html.images.image[1].sizes.size[0]["#text"];
    }
});
```

If I remove dataType: "json" or use POST, it's synchronous again, but I'm dependant on using both json and GET.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ah, this is because you're trying to do cross-domain requests, and cross-domain requests rely on a dynamic script tag, which can never be synchronous, must use datatype json and the GET method.

If you do a POST or remove the datatype, you will get an access error because of [same-origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy. It will return immediately, but as a failure.

Comment: hmmm, guess I will have to find another way then... thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: Could he bring the JSON string back as text and parse the JSON string to an object himself in his success() function using json2.js from www.json.org?

Comment: @Lunchy Not without something to handle redirecting the request on his side. The only way to get data in from another domain is to use the script tag and a callback function. It definitely appears that the service is geared towards exactly that by specifying the callback function as a URL. You can simulate blocking, but only using Javascript 1.7. http://hyperstruct.net/2008/5/17/synchronous-invocation-in-javascript-part-1-problem-and-basic-solution http://www.neilmix.com/2007/02/07/threading-in-javascript-17/